# Filter out DQ issues in column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where I am seeing duplicate rows. I am seeing DQ issues for the supplier name. Some rows are missing the supplier code (3213) or are simply not known.

| NK_1 | PRODUCT | SUPPLIER | HASH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32187 | Mango | Happy Fruits | a160d756c2f0dbd88f1b07b82a504fc6 |
| 32187 | Mango | Happy Fruits (3213) | 9b08d35d051bc0cc08188b17c0bc9180 |
| 32187 | Mango | Not Known | 634b8c15cbb6f0b41c05542f07af5664 |
| 32187 | Mango | Happy Fruits (3213) | 097bfc53b4bbcb45078baf9bb8a601b20 |

I want to filter for all rows where the Company name and code are present. This table contains thousands of different products and has the DQ issue with every supplier. How best to tackle this situation in your opinion?

Comment: Please tag a database management system (For example SQL Server, MYSQL).

Comment: What is the precise pattern for a string that meets your requirements for the company name and code being present? For example, presumably a company name could include digits so just saying the Supplier must contain alpha characters and numeric characters would not necessarily result in a valid name + code?

Comment: The string i'm looking for is Supplier name + Supplier code.  Happy Fruits (3213) is a valid format. I would only be looking for these.

Comment: So do you mean a string of any alphanumeric characters followed by a space, an opening bracket, 4 digits, a closing bracket and then the string ends?

Answer (score 0):

In sql you can use regexp_like to match patterns in a column
Code example

```
select  nk_1, product, supplier, hash
from dq_table
where 1=1
and regexp_like(supplier, '^\w+.\n{4,}$') 
;
```

The objetive of the regexp is match a pattern that beggin with any letter and end with 4 number characters

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_LIKE()` should do the trick.

Here, I'm looking for one or more words followed by blank, followed by an open parenthesis, by one or more digits and a closed parenthesis:

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(NK_1,PRODUCT,SUPPLIER,HASH) AS (
          SELECT 32187,'Mango','Happy Fruits','a160d756c2f0dbd88f1b07b82a504fc6'
UNION ALL SELECT 32187,'Mango','Happy Fruits (3213)','9b08d35d051bc0cc08188b17c0bc9180'
UNION ALL SELECT 32187,'Mango','Not Known','634b8c15cbb6f0b41c05542f07af5664'
UNION ALL SELECT 32187,'Mango','Happy Fruits (3213)','097bfc53b4bbcb45078baf9bb8a601b20'
)
SELECT
 *
FROM indata
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(supplier,'(\w+ )+[(]\d+[)]')
```

Result:

| NK_1 | PRODUCT | SUPPLIER | HASH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32,187 | Mango | Happy Fruits (3213) | 9b08d35d051bc0cc08188b17c0bc9180 |
| 32,187 | Mango | Happy Fruits (3213) | 097bfc53b4bbcb45078baf9bb8a601b20 |